# .htaccess to redirect folder as query parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please, I would need make htaccess file to redirect folder into query parameter:

```
my.domain/auth?name=Jirka&pass=password
```

To:

```
my.domain?command=auth&name=Jirka&pass=password
```

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect  this:

```
auth?name=Jirka&pass=password
```

You should match first the URI which is `auth` as well as query string `name=Jirka&pass=password` like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^command
RewriteRule ^(.*)    http://your.domain?command=$1&%1 [L]
```